# Linear Regression for iid sample: The value of $E(\epsilon_i^2|x_i)$ is not the same across i. Why?

Tags: regression

Linear Regression for iid sample (Y,X).

$E(\epsilon_i^2|X)=E(\epsilon_i^2|x_i)$, where $x_i$ is the i-th observation of k regressors, and epsilon is the error term.

The book I'm using states that from an iid sample we can deduce that $E(\epsilon_i^2)$ is constant across i, and also the functional form of $E(\epsilon_i^2|x_i)$ across i.

However, the value of $E(\epsilon_i^2|x_i)$ is not the same across i. Why is this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where you write "the value of $E(\epsilon_i^2|x_i)$ is not the same across $i$," do you perhaps mean to refer to the *regression residuals* rather than the error term?  If not, your question seems to contradict itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is linear regression, we *assume* the relation

$$y_i = \mathbf x_i'\beta + \epsilon_i,\;\; \forall i$$

and so the i.i.d. sample of size $n$ is, given our assumption, a collection of observations

$$\{y_i,\mathbf x_i\}_{\{i\in [1,n]\}} = \{\mathbf x_i'\beta + \epsilon_i,\mathbf x_i\}_{\{i\in [1,n]\}}$$

Note that we consider the statement "i.i.d. sample" to pertain to the *joint distribution of the sample*, i.e. of the $y$'s and the $\mathbf x_i$'s. This is the approach usually adopted in Econometrics (see for example [Hayashi (2000) ch 1 p. 12](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s6946.pdf) - **legally downloadable**). Viewed in this light, the "i.i.d. assumption" has some implications for the marginal distribution of the errors, as well as for autocorrelation (it implies no-autocorrelation of the errors), but it does not cover conditional homo/heteroskedasticity.

Specifically, if the sample is (or we assume it to be) i.i.d., then due to the assumed decomposition of $y_i$, it follows from the above that the $\epsilon_i$'s are i.i.d. and so 
$$E(\epsilon_i^2) = E(\epsilon_j^2),\;\; \forall i,j \in [1,n]$$

Also

$$E(\epsilon_i^2 \mid \mathbf x_i) = E((y_i - \mathbf x_i'\beta)^2 \mid \mathbf x_i) = E(y_i^2 - 2y_i\mathbf x_i'\beta+ (\mathbf x_i'\beta)^2 \mid \mathbf x_i)$$

$$=E(y_i^2 \mid\mathbf x_i) - 2\mathbf x_i'\beta E(y_i \mid \mathbf x_i) + (\mathbf x_i'\beta)^2 $$

The $\mathbf x_i$'s may be i.i.d. but this does not mean that each actual realization is identical (this would turn the regressors into constants). So, *without further assumptions*, in general we will have

$$E(\epsilon_i^2\mid\mathbf x_i ) \neq E(\epsilon_j^2\mid\mathbf x_j),\;\; i,j \in [1,n]$$

In other words conditional homoskedasticity must be imposed as an *additional* assumption. Note also that the assumption of  strict exogeneity (or mean-independence) of the error vector with respect to  the regressor matrix, $E(\epsilon \mid \mathbf X) = 0$, which for an i.i.d. sample is equivalent to $E(\epsilon_i \mid \mathbf x_i) = 0,\; \forall i$, does not bring about conditional homoskedasticity, the latter remaining a distinct assumption.

Comment: Why doesn't the iid assumption imply "conditional homoskedasticity"?

Comment: @whuber I would say because it is a statement about "inter-observation" marginal/joint distributions, and not about "intra-observation" conditional ones? The law of Total Variance together with i.i.d. and strict exogeneity, impose only that all conditional variances have the same expected value. And the conditioning set $\mathbf x_i$ differs for each $i$, although it is identically distributed. Am I missing something?

Comment: Alecos Many thanks for your answer. Have some doubts about it though.Could you elaborate more on $E(y_i^2|x_i)$, namely on the distribution of $y_i|x_i$, without referring to the error term. $E(y_i|x_i)$ is a constant so there  is no need for elaboration here. But the other, I would like to know if from $(y_i,x_i)\sim F$ what we can say about $y_i|x_i\sim$?

Comment: $E(y_i|\mathbf x_i)$ is not a constant - it is equal to $\mathbf x_i'\beta$, which is not constant. These conditional expected values are not with respect to a specific value of the regressors, but to their sigma-algebras. Apart from that, the conditional distribution for each $i$ is exactly the subject of additional assumptions, we cannot "pin down" the conditional variance from the i.i.d. assumption.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, $x_i'\beta$ is not a constant. As to the answer to the last question in my previous comment, you say that we cannot pin down the conditional variance from the iid assumption.  But can we pin down something? (from the book I would say the functional form of the distribution can be pin downed) How or why?

Comment: I don't think you're missing anything, Alecos, but perhaps there are some different interpretations occurring. To me, the first line "linear regression for iid sample" means there exists an (unknown, vector) parameter $\beta$ such that the random variables $(Y-X\beta)|X$ are independent and all have the same distribution. At some level you seem to be adopting a different interpretation in which $(X,Y)$ has some (arbitrary?) bivariate distribution. I'm not completely sure what your assumptions are--but they do seem to lead you to different conclusions than my interpretation does.

Comment: @whuber ok, I get it now. Yes this is where our interpretations differ. By "i.i.d sample" I understand a statement about the joint distribution of the regressors and the dependent variable, perhaps because the actual sample contains values of $X$'s and $Y$'s, so any characterization of it seems natural, to me, to pertain to the data generating mechanism of these values. CONTD

Comment: @whuber CONTD Even seen in this light, the assumption does imply some things about the errors, like no-autocorrelation for example, or identical unconditional moments, but it does not cover conditional hetero/homskedasticity. I believe this is the approach usually adopted in Econometrics, for example Hayashi 2000, p.12, explicitly points out that under an i.i.d. sample, the conditional homo/heteroskedasticity assumption remains a distinct one.

Comment: Thank you. If you get a chance, it would be nice if you could incorporate this explicit characterization of your assumptions within your answer.

Comment: @whuber. Done as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the value of $E(\epsilon_i^2|x_i)$ is not the same across i.
>   Why is this?

Let's first clarify that your book is most likely talking about the errors, not the residuals. The difference is that the former is not observable, while the latter is. Regression assumes that the *true* model is $y=X\beta+\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is a random *error*. It's not observable.

The regression modeling will try to estimate the coefficients, and will come up with $y=Xb+e$, where $b$ is the estimated coefficients, and $e$ - residuals (estimated error). You are hoping that at least $X$ is correct, i.e. that you added all the true predictors, and didn't add wrong predictors. You hope that your model is correctly specified, then go ahead with estimating $b$ and $e$. Note, that at any moment you **do not** observe true errors $\varepsilon$. Therefore, your statement above seems to be stemming from confusion of errors and residuals. You can't really state that expectations of errors are correlated with predictors, because you don't observe them. You don't observe erros, and it's even less observable are their expectations. You can suspect that they are, and run some tests on *residuals* to support your suspicion.

The residuals are observable, of course. You estimated them. How are you going to estimate the expectation of residuals like in your statement above? You observe individual residuals $e_i$, but how would get $E[e_i]$? On the other hand $E[e|X]=0$ is guaranteed by the regression. It's just how the regression works: it will estimate residuals in such a way that this will be held true.